# Mask Brush Not Showing in Sculpt Mode

Tags: sculpt, visibility

When I select the Mask tool in Sculpt Mode and try to paint, nothing shows up.
Mask is turned on in Overlays and set to 1.0.
The Strength is set to 1.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Ctrl M used to be the shortcut to hide the mask but it doesn't exist in the latest versions, what version are you using? Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/